# How to design tabitems, without having them in a .xml file

Tags: android

I want to design my tabitems from a tablayout, but the tabs are not made in my .xml file. I don't know exactly where my tabs get generated, but it looks like it happens in a adapter

Normally you would make a drawable to design views like buttons, but can I do this also for tabs in a tabLayout?

My MainActivity doesn't create tabItems on startup, and I'm only gathering the data for the fragments here

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstance)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstance);

        recentCardItems = new ArrayList<>();
        followingCardItems = new ArrayList<>();

        //This method sets the views in the abstract class DrawerLayoutActivity
        setMenuLayoutElements(R.layout.activity_main, R.id.toolbar_main, R.id.drawer_layout_main);
        setCardAdapterToReviewList();
        configureFireStoreToLoadNewReviewsIntoList();
    }
```

My adapter class, with the tabs "All" and "Following"

```
final int PAGE_COUNT = 2;
    private String tabTitles[] = new String[] { "All", "Following" };
    private Context context;
    private List<CardItem> cardItemsRecent;
    private List<CardItem> cardItemsFollowing;

    private RecyclerViewFragment fragmentRecent;
    private RecyclerViewFragment fragmentFollowing;

    public RecyclerFragmentAdapter(FragmentManager fm, Context context, List<CardItem> cardItemsRecent, List<CardItem> cardItemsFollowing) {
        super(fm);
        this.context = context;
        this.cardItemsRecent = cardItemsRecent;
        this.cardItemsFollowing = cardItemsFollowing;

        this.fragmentRecent = RecyclerViewFragment.newInstance(cardItemsRecent, R.layout.fragement_recyclerview_home, R.id.recyclerView);
        this.fragmentFollowing = RecyclerViewFragment.newInstance(cardItemsFollowing, R.layout.fragment_recyclerview_following, R.id.reyclerViewFollowing);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return PAGE_COUNT;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        Fragment fragmentToReturn;
        switch (position)
        {
            case 0:
                fragmentToReturn = fragmentRecent;
                break;

            case 1:
                fragmentToReturn = fragmentFollowing;
                break;

            default:
                fragmentToReturn = null;
        }
        return fragmentToReturn;
    }
    
//this getPageTitle method seems like it generates the titles of my tabs
    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        // Generate title based on item position
        return tabTitles[position];
    }

    public RecyclerViewFragment getFragmentRecent() {
        return fragmentRecent;
    }

    public RecyclerViewFragment getFragmentFollowing() {
        return fragmentFollowing;
    }
```

As shown here my xml.file doesn't have tabitems

```
<LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
            <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                android:id="@+id/sliding_tabs"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:tabMode="fixed" />

            <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                android:id="@+id/viewpager"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"/>

        </LinearLayout>
```

Also here in this image you can see it

[image: the selected area is my tablayout]

I'm expecting a tabitem which I can give an @drawable shape, so it has a custom made layout, like a white background or something.

This is what my MainActivity shows at the moment
[image: The homepage]

Answer (score 0):

you can directly add tabs to tablayout using **addTab** method.

```
    tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    tabLayout.addTab(new TabLayout.newTab().setText("All"));
    tabLayout.addTab(new TabLayout.newTab().setText("Following"));
```

Comment: As you can see in the picture the tabs are already there, so it looks like a weird solution but I'll give it a try